# Delphi: problem with httpcli (ICS) post method

Tags: delphi, post, httpclient

I am using HttpCli component form ICS to POST a request. I use an example that comes with the component. It says:

```
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Data : String;
begin
    Data:='status=no';
    HttpCli1.SendStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    HttpCli1.SendStream.Write(Data[1], Length(Data));
    HttpCli1.SendStream.Seek(0, 0);
    HttpCli1.RcvdStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    HttpCli1.URL := Trim('http://server/something');
    HttpCli1.PostAsync;
end;
```

But it fact, it sends not

> status=no

but

> s.t.a.t.u

I can't understand, where is the problem. Maybe someone can show an example, how to send POST request with the help of HttpCli component?

PS I can't use Indy =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you're using Delphi 2009 or later, where the `string` type holds two-byte-per-character Unicode data. The `Length` function gives the number of *characters*, not the number of *bytes*, so when you put your string into the memory stream, you only copy *half* the bytes from the string. Even if you'd copied all of them, though, you'd still have a bunch of extra data in the stream since each character has two bytes and the server probably only expects to get one.

Use a different string type, such as `AnsiString` or `UTF8String`.